# Wrapping overloaded functions with function with union types as argument

Tags: typescript, overloading, union-types

Consider 4 functions that are overloading each other (external library, so I don't want to be changing this):

```js
addListener(eventName: 'change', listenerFunc: ChangeListener): Promise < PluginListenerHandle > & PluginListenerHandle;
addListener(eventName: 'open', listenerFunc: OpenListener): Promise < PluginListenerHandle > & PluginListenerHandle;
addListener(eventName: 'restore', listenerFunc: RestoreListener): Promise < PluginListenerHandle > & PluginListenerHandle;
addListener(eventName: 'back', listenerFunc: BackListener): Promise < PluginListenerHandle > & PluginListenerHandle;
```

I want to wrap all of them in a separate function so I can wrap code around the callback (Angular zone in this case):

```js
wrapListenerCallback<T extends Listener>(eventName: T, callableFunction: ListenerCallback) {
    return addListener(eventName, (data) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => { // irrelevant
            callableFunction(data)
        })
    })
}
```

With my current implementation I'm getting 2 errors:

```
Argument of type 'Listener' is not assignable to parameter of type '"back"'.
Type '"change"' is not assignable to type '"back"'.ts(2769)
```

Once I replace the first addListener argument with 'open' I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'OpenEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent & OpenEvent & RestoreEvent & BackEvent'.
```

For context the models:

`from external library`:

```
export interface ChangeEvent {
    argument: boolean; // irrelevant
}
export interface OpenEvent {
    argument: boolean; // irrelevant
    argument2?: any; // irrelevant
}
export interface RestoreEvent {
    argument: string; // irrelevant
    argument2: string; // irrelevant
}
export interface BackEvent {
    argument: string; // irrelevant
}


export declare type ChangeListener = (event: ChangeEvent) => void;
export declare type OpenListener = (event: OpenEvent) => void;
export declare type RestoreListener = (event: RestoreEvent) => void;
export declare type BackListener = (event: BackEvent) => void;

export interface PluginListenerHandle {
    remove: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

`own project`:

```
export type Listener = 'change' | 'open' | 'restore' | 'back'
export type ListenerCallback = ChangeListener | OpenListener | RestoreListener | BackListener
```

How can I input one of type Listener to addListener() and get back (output) of one of type ListenerCallback but not ListenerCallback itself?

Minimum reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/module-augmentation-forked-xotvld?file=/index.ts (thanks to @jcalz for providing most of it)

Comment: I really wish this were a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Is `addListener` a function or a method of something?  What's `ngZone`?  Do we need that to answer the question?  Ideally I could drop the example as-is into the TS Playground and get it working, instead of worrying about whether the setup is close enough to yours.

Comment: @jcalz `addListener` are functions from the CapacitorJS library, ngZone is an angular function that will execute the code synchronously to the angular zone but its irrelevant for the question. I just want to be able to wrap the callback for all 4 overloaded functions in a single function. Will try to provide a TSPlayground link soon.

Comment: Ideally nothing irrelevant for the question would be included, so as to avoid distraction.  Also note that I didn't ask for a playground link; while such a link would be helpful, the important part is that the plain text code in the question constitutes a [mre] if someone were to paste it into an IDE.  I think in your case you want to have at least two files, since your external library is going to be imported.  I'm trying to get something like that set up in stackblitz but it's fighting me

Comment: My suggestion is that you use module augmentation to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) a proper generic call signature to the external `addListener()` as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/module-augmentation-3yh53o?file=/lib.d.ts).  Note that this doesn't go against "external library, so I don't want to be changing this"; you aren't touching the external library files, it just makes `addListener()` easier to call.  If this meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the suggestions! I changed my question accordingly. I will have a look at your link. Meanwhile I forked your codesandbox example to produce the errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/module-augmentation-forked-xotvld?file=/index.ts